# How can I use another drive with Owncloud?

Tags: owncloud-server

I have Owncloud installed and working, but I want it to use my secondary hard drive as opposed to the drive I have Ubuntu installed on. How is this possible?

The [documentation](http://owncloud.org/support/custom-mount-configuration/) is rather confusing and outdated (I'm using Owncloud 5).

Comment: BTW, the documentation you are seeing is to make your own type of "External storage" for the External storage support module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For allowing the use of a personalized storage media, you need the External Storage module enabled in your Apps.

[image]

Once you have enabled this module, you will have new options in the Admin page called External Storage. Configure the Folder name, the type (if it's Local, Google Drive, WebDAV, etc.), the configuration (in the case of a Local, the target directory) and the users with access.

[image]

Once you have ended, you can go to the main screen and you will find a directory with the name of the resource.

[image]

That's all.

Comment: Enabling the module worked, but the folder doesn't show up. It seems to be a permissions issue, but nothing seems to be fixing that.

Comment: @RolandiXor did external storage module appear in the Admin dashboard?

Comment: yes. However, it seems not work. I think Owncloud is just plain broken for me :(

Answer (score 1):

ownCloud save all files in /var/www/owncloud/data.

You may open '/var/www/ownclou/config/config.php' and search for ‘datadirectory’. Replace ‘/var/www/owncloud/data’ with your shared folder full path. Make sure ownCloud has enough privilege to write to that folder.

You may see detail in **[Assign a different Directory in ownCloud to Store All Backup Files](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/assign-a-different-directory-in-owncloud-to-store-all-backup-files/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/new_mnt_drive
```

More info at:
http://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/admin_manual/configuration/custom_mount_config_gui.html